# How to adjust relative transparency of ggplot2 points

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha-transparency

I want to make some points stand out on a ggplot2 chart by giving them less transparency while the rest fade to the background.  But no matter what two alpha values I give the sets of points, their relative transparency is the same.

Here's `0.8` vs `0.7`:

```
x <- mtcars
x$opacity <- ifelse(x$cyl == 6, 0.8, 0.7)

ggplot(x, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = cyl, alpha = opacity)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot2 scatterplot with 0.8 and 0.7 alpha for two sets of points]

And here's `0.8` vs `0.1` -- looks the same:

```
x$opacity <- ifelse(x$cyl == 6, 0.8, 0.1)

ggplot(x, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = cyl, alpha = opacity)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot2 scatterplot with 0.8 and 0.1 alpha for two sets of points]
How can I fine-tune that relative alpha so that the two sets are closer in transparency?  Right now the values of the two numbers don't seem to matter.  Specifically, in this case I want the darker points (with the higher alpha) to be more transparent.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are trying to pass actual alpha values to the aesthetic mapping, be sure to use

```
scale_alpha_identity()
```

Otherwise ggplot will rescale your values just like it created the colors for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Add scale_alpha_continuous to your plot and define the range. e.g.

```
scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.7, 0.8))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mapping the values 0.7 and 0.8 to alpha, not necessarily *using* them for alpha. A quicker way is to map the condition and then set alpha:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = cyl, alpha = cyl == 6)) +
    geom_point() + 
    scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.2, 0.8))
#> Warning: Using alpha for a discrete variable is not advised.
```

[image: points with alpha]